# Most optimized way in Java 8 to query results database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, java-8

Currently I am working on a Spring/Hibernate project using Java 8.

I am now at a point where I have to query results from my local MySQL database.

I came up with two ways of doing this:

1. Jinq which utilizes Java 8 streams:

   ```
   customers.where(
       c -> c.getCountry().equals("Belgium")
   );
   ```
2. Hibernate query (HQL):

   ```
   Query query = session.createQuery("from Customers where Country = 'Belgium' ");
   List list = query.list();
   ```

Using timestamps, I was able to test the time of execution (Jinq took less time to query than HQL).

But performance-wise, is Jinq the best fit for the scenario here?  Is there another way to query that is even more optimized?  Eventually, the project will query every 10 minutes against 300,000 to 1,000,000 results.

Thanks.

Comment: for performance the  best for my experience  are raw  queries ..

Comment: If the ORM uses reflection to wrap query results in your custom classes it will always be slower than raw queries. So, if you don't need an ORM, don't use it, raw queries are faster. Anyway note that speed should not really be an issue, ORMs are often used in enterprise environments and they don't affect performance that much, so  if you need an ORM just choose the one that better fits your needs.

Comment: If you're going to run a query returning a million records, you should use JDBC directly, so you can process the rows as they are retrieved, keeping the memory footprint down. You don't want to use an API that returns a `LIst` of marshaled objects.

Comment: "every 10 minutes against 1 mil results" is a small enough query you should be able to get as fast as you like and the _interface_ to your db is least likely going to be a non-factor.

Comment: @Andreas it's not entirely clear from the question whether there will be 300k to a million results or the query will be run against that many rows. Maybe the latter because the former sounds kind of pointless.

Comment: One query every 10 minutes?

Comment: @pvg OP said "results", but I did qualify my comment anyway, so what is your point? And why do you think a large query is pointless?

Comment: @Andreas my point is exactly the one I made. Not sure why you find this upsetting.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should really be making sure that the DB tables have appropriate indexes with respect to your query predicates. If you're doing full table scans with each query because of poor execution plans, then it doesn't really matter which abstraction layer you're using on the Java side.

Answer (score 1):

Right now if you are simply doing full table scans with each query, it shouldn't matter which one you use.

At the same time, if you are interested in the pure performance, you should just use raw queries.

Personally, I have a project that might be similar in scale to yours, and my JINQ always takes shorter.  So just go with your JINQ solution should be good enough.

With more details I can offer additional help.